# How to add a target_blank in to this?

Tags: javascript, target

On of my friends has a homepage and also a script on it where people can book his hostel. Today when people using the form the go directly from his page to booking.com. Is there any way to add so people open booking.com in a new TAB?

This is the code given from booking.com:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.booking.com/general.html?tmpl=bookit;aid=330843;lang=sv;hotel_id=260079"></script>
```

Comment: No you can't modify anything in the script, cause its not hosted on your system

Comment: How is that script added to the page?  Is it just embedded in the page or is it loaded when you click a button or link or something?  We need more information.  What have you already tried?

Comment: Is it the code creating dynamicaly ?

Comment: The form is created on the page by the javascript from booking.com. Either they have a parameter that is passed in the script URL that makes the submitted form open in a new window (probably not), or you write a script that alters the created HTML by adding `target="_blank"` to the FORM element.

Answer (score 0):

Add this, after that script is included in the page...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("b_availFrm").target = "_blank";
</script>
```

The script embeds a form on the page with the id of `b_availFrm`.  The above code sets the target of that form to `_blank`, which means when you click the submit button it will open the results in a new tab or window (depending on the browser settings).

**[Here's a working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pDBN6/1/)**